Is it permissible to call someone divine?
For example when we call someone pretty we say you look divine. Is it considered a shirk?

If you see an English dictionary the word 'divine' has multiple meanings:

connected with a god, or like a god
extremely good, pleasant, or enjoyable

If you used the word in the second sense it would not be shirk as you do not mean to ascribe godhood to the person. Although you may want to avoid it if it will cause confusion or can be misinterpreted. muftionline.co.za has a fatwa claiming to be from a Mufti which states that it is permissible to call food divine.


لَا يُؤَاخِذُكُمُ اللَّهُ بِاللَّغْوِ فِي أَيْمَانِكُمْ وَ لَكِنْ
يُؤَاخِذُكُمْ بِمَا كَسَبَتْ قُلُوبُكُمْ وَ اللَّهُ غَفُورٌ حَلِيمٌ
Allah does not impose blame upon you for what is unintentional in your
oaths, but He imposes blame upon you for what your hearts have earned.
And Allah is Forgiving and Forbearing.

, AFAIK.

Read the article on IslamQA called, "Is it possible for praise of a created being or love of football to reach the level of worship?"
In summary, it is haram and according to some, shirk
Allah knows best
